# Error in MLP Classifier in pyspark fit method

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am using **MultilayerPerceptronClassifier** from **pyspark.ml.classification**
My dataset has 11 **features**

```
['fixed acidity',
 'volatile acidity',
 'citric acid',
 'residual sugar',
 'chlorides',
 'free sulfur dioxide',
 'total sulfur dioxide',
 'density',
 'pH',
 'sulphates',
 'alcohol']
```

and my **label** consists of 7 classes.

```
-----+
|label|
+-----+
|    6|
|    3|
|    5|
|    9|
|    4|
|    8|
|    7|
+-----+
```

I am using MultiLayerPerceptronClassifier model in pyspark to train my dataset. According to the pyspark ML convention I have specified my neural net architecture in this format

```
# specify layers for the neural network:
# input layer of size 11 (features), two intermediate of size 5 and 4
# and output of size 7 (classes)
layers = [11,5,4,7]
```

I am specifying my classifier

```
clf = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(labelCol='label',layers=layers)
```

Now, I am training with my train data

```
cvModel = clf.fit(train_data)
```

Could anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

**Error**:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o241.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 47.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 812, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LabelConverter$.encodeLabeledPoint(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier$$anonfun$3.apply(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier$$anonfun$3.apply(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:238)
```

Comment: Try after changing label in the range [0-6] and [1-7]. One of these may work.

Comment: I did that. When I am trying to get the hyperparameter `cvModel.bestModel.stages[0]._java_obj.getMaxIter()`. I am getting an error that `py4j.Py4JException: Method getStepSize([])` does not exist. Could you tell me how to resolve this error?